# Position of Image after zooming inside the Canvas in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am developing an Windows Phone application where I am having one image inside the Grid. User is allowed to zoom the image and can crop the particular region.

In default Scale=1, I am getting everything which works as usual. But If user zoomed the image and tried to get the position of cropping rectangle inside the image does not return the correct value.

Ex: In Position (0,0) with Zoom Factor 1 gives the correct cropped region in the image. But if position is (0,0) with Zoom factor is 2 gives the empty cropped region as Image is not available in the framework base.

```
var compositeTransform = new CompositeTransform
            {
                ScaleX=transform.ScaleX,
                ScaleY=transform.ScaleY,
                TranslateX=transform.X,
                TranslateY=transform.Y
            };

            var wBitmap = new WriteableBitmap((int)PickedImage.ActualWidth,(int)PickedImage.ActualHeight);

            wBitmap.Render(PickedImage, compositeTransform);
            wBitmap.Invalidate();

            Point point = PickedImage.TransformToVisual(cropper).Transform(new Point(0, 0));

            var cropped = wBitmap.Crop((int) (-point.X), (int) (-point.Y), (int) (cropper.ActualWidth),
                (int) (cropper.ActualHeight));
```

I am having the above code. I want to calculate the "point" which implies the position of Rectangular region in the Image. But I am getting wrong value when Image is zoomed. Can you please anyone help me to get rid off the problem ?